# an appropriate browser plugin for playing flash streams that also plays on Android

Tags: android, flash, streaming, jwplayer

I am trying to setup a web page able to play live and on-demand rtmp streams on a certain rtmp-server. Previously I had success with [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/%E2%80%8E) and I had setup this player to play on pc clients successfully. The java-script I used for live streaming is this:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: rtmp://myStreamURL,
    height: 360,
    image: "../myImage.jpg",
    rtmp: {
        subscribe: true
    },
    autostart: true,
    width: 640
});
```

Now the problem I faced is that when I want to access the web page from Android clients I see an error message on the player screen as:
          `No playable sources found`. 
I am confused that if free version of jwplayer works on android OS as I read on [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28837/browser-device-support/), [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/31646/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711759/using-jwplayer-in-android-for-streaming-video-playback-in-phonegap).
Also maybe some configs or manifast files are needed as explained [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29394/hls-with-mp4-fallback).

Now I want to decide if I need change my player to work on both pc and android clients? Also is can any special change in configuration be effective? Any help would be worthwhile. thank you.

Comment: RTMP is something that only Flash supports, which is no longer being developed for Android. HLS Also does not work reliably across Android devices, which is another issue. The only way I have seen a set up work is to set up a link to an RTSP stream outside of the player set up. We document this work around here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28856/using-apple-hls-streaming

Comment: for example I can see youtube on my android tablet. So what means that there is not support for flash on android?

Comment: I am not sure about RTMP specifically, but in JW6, we do not support Flash or RTMP on Android, HTML5 only. If you are using a YouTube video with the JW Player, it will work on Android devices, though.

Comment: I just need a player to play RTMP streams with web browser on android. I don't know  what browser is used by youtube. Can you introduce an appropriate player to me?

Comment: I don't know of one, sorry....