# how to display html5 page in android web view

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I have a requirement of render a HTML5 page in my web view. This HTML5 page plays a video with the help of JW Player.

While running, web view can not display that video.
This is the URL of the web page.
`http://166.78.178.47:8080/imagedetails?contentId=619&categoryId=`

How to display this html5 page in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry dude its not possible in webview in all version. It may work in KIT-KAT but not in early versions

Comment: Thank you Biraj to respond my question.
 Is there any way to play videos with jw palyer in android

Comment: As my knowledge it is not possible with webview it can play with browser.

Answer (score 0):

Actually am not sure either of this flash Video playback option. Check out this
[JW Player does not support Flash on Android anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711759/using-jwplayer-in-android-for-streaming-video-playback-in-phonegap)

But am eager to know, did you tried HTML5 Video support option in WebView? It supports MP4/WebM(HTML5 supported videos). Look at this
[WebView and HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)

Answer (score 0):

JW Player does not support Flash on Android anymore, as a response to Adobe also dropping Android Flash support. Only HTML5 (and therefore only MP4/WebM) are supported, as of Android 2.3.