# rtmp stream run on phonegap / cordova

Tags: android, html, flash, cordova

From this post ( [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711759/using-jwplayer-in-android-for-streaming-video-playback-in-phonegap) ) I came to know that Adobe stopped supporting flash in android 4.0+ and some versions contain bug.

Now I have a embeded code

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://d.inscripts.in/suno/app/webroot/js/player.swf" width="377" height="240" style="undefined" id="mpl" name="mpl" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="file=Suno1024&amp;streamer=rtmp://media3.streamcom.net:1935/SUNO1024&amp;autostart=true&amp;provider=rtmp">
```

Clearly it will not be loaded due to flash support. This embed code contains rtmp stream source link

```
rtmp://media3.streamcom.net:1935/SUNO1024&amp;autostart=true&amp;provider=rtmp
```

I want to play it in phonegap and android. I tried HTML5. Not worked. Searched for some solution, not found. **Can anyone please tell me how can I run this rtmp source in phonegap application??**

Basically is it possible to run rtmp without flash?

Answer (score 0):

If video is the main functionality of your app, maybe you should have a look at Adobe AIR. Streaming RTSP in HTML5 is not *really* supported. Check out this question ["Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5).